# Terraform init not working in windows 10 pro

Tags: terraform

I recently updated my OS from windows 7 to 10 pro at my work. My scripts work fine everywhere except for on my laptop.
I get the following error

```
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'file://c:/path/to/modules ': failed to run mklink .terraform\modules\b571284e9ec052dbb3f56e5cee0f6674 C:\path\to\modules: exit status 1 "The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n"
```

When i checked, the files are available in the given path but still doesn;t work. I saw previous issues where terraform init was an issue with the windows previlege to run the symblink, so I even tried using the command prompt as an administrator, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun needs to be deleted

Comment: It has been broken on my machine for months, and I couldn't for the live of me figure out why. Thank you!